# How can I set a background image with svelte?

Tags: javascript, date, desktop-application, svelte, datefield

How can I set a background image with svelte?

The code is here for reference: [Svelte sandbox](https://svelte.dev/repl/f137b909d3e740f99a030576189091db?version=3.22.3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got it right. We probably can't use static assets on the REPL but what you did works well with any image from the web:

From your `style` section in `Todos.svelte`:

```
    :global(body){
        background-color: lightseagreen;
        background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/956981/milky-way-starry-sky-night-sky-star-956981.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    }
```